# command prompt xcopy command usage

Tags: command-prompt

I am trying to copy all the files from one folder to the other using cmd as

`xcopy C:\Users\computer\Desktop\Source C:\Users\computer\Desktop\Destination`

for the next time when I use the above command it asks whether to Overwrite Yes/No/All, so here is my question:

Is there any command within xcopy where it automatically overwrites all the files within the Destination folder from Source folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `/y` switch

```
xcopy C:\Users\computer\Desktop\Source C:\Users\computer\Desktop\Destination /y
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the help (French Windows Seven), from cmd.exe.

See /Y argument

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\>help xcopy

Copie des fichiers et des arborescences de répertoires.

XCOPY source [destination] [/A | /M] [/D[:date]] [/P] [/S [/E]] [/V] [/W]
                           [/C] [/I] [/Q] [/F] [/L] [/G] [/H] [/R] [/T] [/U]
                           [/K] [/N] [/O] [/X] [/Y] [/-Y] [/Z] [/B] [/J]
                           [/EXCLUDE:fich1[+fich2][+fich3]...]

 source       Spécifie le ou les fichiers à copier.
 destination  Spécifie l'emplacement et/ou le nom de nouveaux fichiers.
 /A           Copie uniquement les fichiers ayant l'attribut archive, ne
              modifie pas l'attribut.
 /M           Copie uniquement les fichiers ayant l'attribut archive,
              désactive l'attribut archive.
 /D:j-m-a   Copie les fichiers modifiés à partir de la date spécifiée.
              Si aucune date n'est donnée, copie uniquement les fichiers dont
              l'heure source est plus récente que l'heure de destination.
 /EXCLUDE:fich1[+fich2][+fich3]...
              Spécifie une liste de fichiers contenant des chaînes. Chaque
              chaîne doit être placée sur une ligne dans le fichier.
              Lorsque l'une des chaînes est trouvée dans le chemin d'accès
              absolu du fichier devant être copié, ce fichier est exclu de la
              copie. Par exemple, spécifier une chaîne telle que \obj\
              ou .obj exclura respectivement tous les fichiers situés sous
              le répertoire obj ou tous les fichiers dont l'extension
              est .obj.
 /P           Confirmer la création de chaque fichier
              de destination.
 /S           Copie les répertoires et sous-répertoires à l'exception des
              répertoires vides.
 /E           Copie les répertoires et sous-répertoires, y compris les
              répertoires vides.
              Identique à /S /E. Peut être utilisé pour modifier /T.
 /V           Vérifie la taille de chaque nouveau fichier.
 /W           Vous demande d'appuyer sur une touche avant la copie.
 /C           Continuer la copie même si des erreurs se produisent.
 /I           Si la destination n'existe pas et que plus d'un fichier est
              copié, considérer la destination comme devant être
              un répertoire.
 /Q           N'affiche pas les noms de fichiers lors de la copie.
 /F           Affiche les noms de source et de destination complets lors
              de la copie.
 /L           Affiche les fichiers devant être copié.
 /G           Permet la copie des fichiers chiffrés vers des destinations qui
              ne prennent pas en charge le chiffrement.
 /H           Copie également les fichiers cachés et les fichiers système.
 /R           Remplace les fichiers en lecture seule.
 /T           Crée la structure de répertoires mais ne copie pas
              les fichiers.
              N'inclut pas les répertoires ou sous-répertoires vides. /T /E
              incluent les répertoires et sous-répertoires vides.
 /U           Copie seulement les fichiers existants déjà dans la
              destination.
 /K           Copie les attributs. La commande normale Xcopy rétablira les
              attributs de lecture seule.
 /N           Copie en utilisant les noms courts générés.
 /O           Copie les fichiers d'appartenance et les informations d'ACL.
 /X           Copie les paramètres d'audit de fichiers (sous-entend /O).
 /Y           Supprime la demande de confirmation de remplacement de
              fichiers de destination existants.
 /-Y          Provoque la demande de confirmation de remplacement
              d'un fichier de destination existant.
 /Z           Copie les fichiers du réseau en mode redémarrable.
 /B           Copie le lien symbolique et non pas la cible du lien.
 /J           Copie avec E/S sans mémoires tampons. Recommandé pour les gros fichiers.

Le commutateur /Y peut être défini dans la variable d'environnement COPYCMD.
Il peut être remplacé par /-Y dans la ligne de commande.
```